# Mysql - Count date consecutive with condition and get range list

Tags: mysql, date, count, rows

I need to know how many dates a team won (value1 > value2) consecutively and know the date of the first and the last match played won. And show a list of 10 ranges order by won and date.
I know its not easy. Its not easy to me.. I try to make some queries  and  subquery but without good results. Thanks
I have a table With

```
            CREATE TABLE `games` (
              `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `value1` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `value2` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `played` date NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              KEY `played` (`played`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

            insert into games (value1, value2, played)
            values
            ("2", "3", "1943-05-09"),
            ("4", "3", "1943-08-15"),
            ("1", "8", "1943-08-22"),
            ("0", "4", "1943-08-29"),
            ("1", "0", "1943-09-12"),
            ("1", "3", "1943-09-26"),
            ("6", "1", "1943-10-03"),
            ("3", "2", "1943-10-10"),
            ("3", "3", "1944-07-16"),
            ("1", "1", "1944-08-06"),
            ("4", "1", "1944-09-24"),
            ("0", "7", "1944-10-08"),
            ("0", "1", "1945-05-13"), // 1
            ("4", "2", "1945-11-04"), // 2
            ("3", "2", "1946-05-12"), // 3 second 3 consecutives win
            ("4", "2", "1946-11-17"),
            ("2", "2", "1946-11-24"),
            ("1", "5", "1946-12-01"),
            ("1", "0", "1947-05-18"),
            ("3", "0", "1947-10-05"),
            ("2", "3", "1948-11-07"),
            ("0", "1", "1948-11-14"),
            ("1", "4", "1948-11-21"),
            ("3", "1", "1949-06-12"), // 1
            ("4", "0", "1949-06-19"), // 2
            ("5", "1", "1949-07-24"), // 3
            ("3", "1", "1949-08-06")  // 4 first consecutives win
```

I need a result like this

```
            From            To          games_won

            1949-06-12  1949-08-06          4
            1945-11-04  1946-11-17          3
            1943-10-03  1943-10-10          2
            ...
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of wins and the number of rows using variables.  The difference is constant for consecutive wins.  This gives you a value for aggregation to get the final result:

```
select min(played), max(played), count(*)
from (select g.*,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn,
             (@rnw := if(value1 > value2, @rnw + 1, @rnw) as rnw
      from games g cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @rnw := 0) params
      order by played
     ) g
where value1 > value2
group by (rn - rnw);
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff,
I add a ) to line 4.
(@rnw := if(value1 > value2, @rnw + 1, @rnw)) as rnw
and add orders and limit to the last line
group by (rn - rnw) order by count(*) desc, played ASC limit 10;
thanks again.