# Efficient way to list ranges of consecutive records

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table set up like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `cn` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `number` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `desc` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

`number` is usually but *not* necessarily unique.

Most of the table consists of rows with consecutive `number` entries.

e.g.

101010, 101011, 101012, etc.

I've been trying to find an **efficient** way to list ranges of consecutive numbers so I can find out where numbers are "missing" easily. What I'd like to do is list the start number, end number, and number of consecutive rows. Since there can be duplicates, I am using `SELECT DISTINCT(number)` to avoid duplicates.

I've not been having much luck - most of the questions of this type deal with dates and have been hard to generalize. One query was executing forever, so that was a no go. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32021211/6110631) is sort of close but not quite. It uses a `CROSS JOIN`, which sounds like a recipe for disaster when you have millions of records.

What would the best way to do this be? Some answers use joins, which I'm skeptical of performance wise. Right now there are only 50,000 rows, but it will be millions of records within a few days, and so every ounce of performance matters.

The eventual pseudoquery I have in mind is something like:

`SELECT DISTINCT(number) FROM cn WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY [consecutive...] ORDER BY number ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. You can solve by using the difference between `row_number()` and `number` to define groups; gaps are identified by changes in the difference:

```
select type, min(number) first_number, max(number) last_number, count(*) no_records
from (
    select cn.*, row_number() over(order by number) rn
    from cn
    where type = 1
) c
group by type, number - rn
```

Note: window functions avalailable in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3 onwards.

---

In earlier versions, you can emulate `row_number()` with a session variable:

```
select type, min(number) first_number, max(number) last_number, count(*) no_records
from (
    select c.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (select * from cn where type = 1 order by number) c
    cross join (select @rn := 0) r
) c
group by number - rn
```

Comment: Will this work even when the row order is arbitrary? Items that are consecutive are not necessarily added to the table in order. Also, I only need results where `type` = 1, so I can do without the partition. Trying to test this now

Comment: OK, now the query executes, but it doesn't seem to work properly. For example, I get a number as first and last and then the next row has the number right after it and so on. It basically seems like it's just enumerating everything. *occasionally* num_records is greater than 1, but it usually doesn't work. Does this rely on all rows being inserted in `number` order? (not the case for me)

Comment: Looks like adding a `GROUP BY number` in the innermost query fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Is there a good way of doing the same thing with multiple columns? For instance, say I have a description column, and I want to do the same thing except instead of grouping for all consecutive numbers, I only do it when the description is identical

Comment: I have something similiar, but my `number` is a datetime, how can I do the same but for <= 60 seconds?